# 'Help' Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Im getting the error on the console

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn');

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

function openModal() {
  console.log(123);
}
```

```html
<button id="modalBtn" class="button">Click Here</button>

<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
    <p> hello I am a modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing is trying to make a modal open but Im keep on failing.

Comment: Make sure your script comes after your elements

Comment: @Taplar OMG so I was supposed to put the <script src = "Main.js"> </script> on the very bottom of the body section. I didn't knew that <script src = "Main.js"> </script> also gets read in order from top to bottom! Thank You